# SQLalchemy:query returns a non-result

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble in getting the results returned by the stored procedure which is called by sqlalchemy, I am seeing that even though stored procedure is returning an integer sql alcehmy. Result set is set to None, which is causing some issues, can someone tell me whats going on?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SYSDATA].[getCertificateInstallStatus] 
@DVSystemName [varchar](max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @system_state int = (SELECT state FROM SYSDATA.certificate where DVSystemName = @DVSystemName)
if @system_state is not NULL
    Return @system_state
Return 0
END
```

Now executing this stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [SYSDATA].[getCertificateInstallStatus]
        @DVSystemName = N'UATDSG'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Calling this procedure returns:

```
Return Value
0
```

Python error trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.2.7-py3.6-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py",
>   line 1067, in _fetchone_impl
>       return self.cursor.fetchone() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   ......   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.2.7-py3.6-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py",
>   line 1089, in _non_result
>       "This result object does not return rows. " sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return
>   rows. It has been closed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the unexpected results is that the statement in the stored procedure doesn't return a result set, it returns an integer value. This leads to another issue - when a stored procedure returns a non-zero value (using `RETURN` statement) this indicates failure.

You need to change the stored procedure and you have at least two options: 1) return a result set or 2) use an ouptut parameter.

Stored procedure returning a result set:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SYSDATA].[getCertificateInstallStatus] 
    @DVSystemName [varchar](max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT COALESCE([state], 0) AS [SystemState]
    FROM SYSDATA.certificate 
    WHERE DVSystemName = @DVSystemName)

    RETURN 0
END
```

Stored procedure with an output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SYSDATA].[getCertificateInstallStatus] 
    @DVSystemName [varchar](max),
    @SystemState int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @SystemState = COALESCE([state], 0) 
    FROM SYSDATA.certificate 
    WHERE DVSystemName = @DVSystemName

    RETURN 0
END
```